# Issue selecting font from TrueType Collection with LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

I'd like to use the Gill Sans font, which is installed in `/Library/Fonts/GillSans.ttc` on my Mac. According to the `fontspec` documentation, I should be able to use TrueType Collections by specifying the font index. The documentation claims this should work with LuaTeX, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

> Support for TrueType Collections has only been tested in XeTeX, but should also work with an up-to-date version of LuaTeX and the `luaotfload` package.

The following minimal document works insofar as it does use Gill Sans, and it seems possible to even use specific weights/shapes of the font by defining a new font family, but it does not work to `\setmainfont` and be able to use commands like `\textbf{}`, `\textit{}`, *etc.*, as can be seen in the screenshot of the output from compiling this document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.ttc,
  UprightFeatures={FontIndex=0},
  BoldFeatures={FontIndex=4},
  ItalicFeatures={FontIndex=2},
  BoldItalicFeatures={FontIndex=5}]{GillSans}

\newfontfamily\SemiBold[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.ttc,
  UprightFeatures={FontIndex=4}]{GillSans}

\begin{document}
\textbf{asdf}
\textit{asdf}
asdf
\textbf{\textit{asdf}}

{\SemiBold asdf}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from compiling document where "asdf" appears in the same font, except when switching to the \SemiBold font]

Does anyone know what the issue might be and how to resolve it? The log shows the following:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/GillSans(0)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/GillSans(0)/m/n' instead on input line 18.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/GillSans(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/GillSans(0)/m/n' instead on input line 19.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/GillSans(0)/b/it' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/GillSans(0)/b/n' instead on input line 21.
```

Moreover, running the following command at a shell

```
luaotfload-tool --find 'Gill Sans SemiBold' -i
```

returns the following, which suggests that the above document should work to pick out the semi bold font as the BoldFont via index 4:

```
luaotfload | resolve : Font "Gill Sans SemiBold" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/Library/Fonts/GillSans.ttc", subfont nr. 4


** 1 Gill Sans SemiBold ********************************************************

        ascender: 1487
    averagewidth: 1154
     boundingbox: <table>
                   1: -1162
                   2: -512
                   3: 2279
                   4: 1931
       capheight: 1397
  defaultvheight: 0
       descender: -561
          family: Gill Sans
        fontname: GillSans-SemiBold
        fullname: Gill Sans SemiBold
     italicangle: 0.0
      monospaced: false
    panoseweight: demi
     panosewidth: normal
       pfmweight: 600
        pfmwidth: 5
   platformnames: <table>
           macintosh: <table>
                  family: Gill Sans
                fullname: Gill Sans SemiBold
          postscriptname: GillSans-SemiBold
               subfamily: SemiBold
             windows: <table>
                  family: Gill Sans
                fullname: Gill Sans SemiBold
          postscriptname: GillSans-SemiBold
               subfamily: SemiBold
       subfamily: SemiBold
    subfontindex: 4
           units: 2048
         version: 13.0d1e4
          weight: semibold
           width: normal
         xheight: 934
```

I'm using MacTeX 2020, v3.14/2020-05-06 of the `luaotfload-tool`, and v2.7i of `fontspec`.

Comment: You might also be able to use the display/series name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with ttc files, you shouldn't use `Extension` but add `.ttc` directly to the name, otherwise it is detected too late and you have to set `ItalicFont`/`BoldFont`/`BoldItalicFont` manually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  UprightFeatures={FontIndex=0},
  BoldFeatures={FontIndex=4},
  ItalicFeatures={FontIndex=2},
  BoldItalicFeatures={FontIndex=5}]{GillSans.ttc}

\newfontfamily\SemiBold[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.ttc,
  UprightFeatures={FontIndex=4}]{GillSans}

\begin{document}
\textbf{asdf}
\textit{asdf}
asdf
\textbf{\textit{asdf}}

{\SemiBold asdf}
\end{document}
```